# Setting up a Many-to-Many relation of a table with itself with DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, many-to-many, dbix-class

I am porting an application from [Class::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aDBI) to [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass) and need help. I have a table `T` with a primary key tid and another table `ChildT` that relates a row of `T` to multiple (child) rows of `T` itself. How can I setup the relations between `T` and `ChildT` so that I can find all children of an instance of `T`. Here are the stripped down versions of these two tables:

```
T: (id, name);
ChildT: (rowid, tid, childid)
```

`tid` and `childid` both reference the `id` column of `T`.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the DBIx::Class::Manual - especially the Cookbook, which has various examples of doing many-to-many relations? Did what is explained in there not work for you? What was the error you got?

Comment: I did. The Cookbook and the Relationship docs explain how to do it when the link table contains foreign keys of two distinct tables. So I know how to do it for Actor -> ActorRole <- Role. What I want is to setup something for (say) Actor -> CoStar <- Actor. Should I set up two belongs_to relationships in the Costar Class - one for each foreign key and two has_many relations from Actor to Costar class? Confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

The [DBIx::Class::Relationship](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::Relationship) docs explain this clearly enough. In the ChildT Class define a `belongs_to` relationship to `T` using the foreign key `childid`:

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(parent => 'App::Schema::Result::T', 'childid');
```

In the T Class define a has_many and a many_to_many relation with the ChildT class:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(childrecords => 'App::Schema::Result::ChildT', 'tid');
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many(children => 'childrecords', 'parent');
```

With this `$t->children` gives all child records of any instance of `T`.